# Taking some personal items to son resident in ireland

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, ireland, customs, imports

I want to be able to gift some personal items taking them by car ferry to my son in ireland from England. These include some "heirloom" items, one being a cased stuffed fish caught in ireland by his father as well as books and some small pieces of furniture.
We actually moved from Ireland in 2020-so effectively taking these items back. We have no receipts for these items. What do we need to do?

Comment: What is the value of the items? https://www.revenue.ie/en/customs/individuals/info-travelling-duty-free/from-outside-eu/calculate.aspx You could try contacting [Customs](https://www.revenue.ie/en/contact-us/customs-ports-and-airports/customs-policy-and-procedural-support.aspx)

Comment: Value of items nothing or minimal as personal used goods so maybe will pass under the €430? exemption from tarriff- but at the whim of  Customs so will contact them beforehand. Thanks